# How to open 3D touch pop pages in the same WKWebView when allowsLinkPreview enabled?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, 3dtouch

When set `webView.allowsLinkPreview = true`, links support 3D touch peek & pop feature. The only problem is the new page will open in Safari instead of the `webView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple iOS 10 introduced a new API for WKWebView allowing you to intercept the peek and pop actions of the link preview by using the following delegate methods:

```
optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,  previewingViewControllerForElement elementInfo: WKPreviewElementInfo,  defaultActions previewActions: [WKPreviewActionItem]) -> UIViewController?
optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,  commitPreviewingViewController previewingViewController: UIViewController)
```

Just use the second delegate method to present the url in your own tab or load it in your own WKWebView.

Source: [iOS 10 Link Preview API in WKWebView](https://webkit.org/blog/7016/ios-10-link-preview-api-in-wkwebview/)